# How do I create a shapefile from a GeoPandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, csv, geopandas

I'm having issues writing a GeoPandas DataFrame to a shapefile using the GeoDataFrame.to_file() function. When I run the code below, sometimes I get an empty shapefile, and sometimes it runs but returns nothing at all.

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
import glob
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\\GY539_Programming\\project_data'
ws = arcpy.env.workspace

files = glob.glob(ws + '/*.csv')
for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])]
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='EPSG:4326', geometry=geometry)
    gdf.to_file('file.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Any advice? My data comes from a csv file that contains one column with longitude coordinates and another with latitude coordinates. Here is a snippet of it:

```
              Api  Permit  ... Latitude Longitude
0     5.000000e+13  163019  ...    61.14   -149.98
1     5.000000e+13  100001  ...    61.21   -149.77
2     5.000000e+13  163015  ...    61.33   -149.91
3     5.000000e+13  165037  ...    61.30   -149.99
4     5.000000e+13  100002  ...    61.42   -149.81
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Could it be that `files` returns an empty list?

Comment: Aslo in each for loop iteration you save with the filename `file.shp` and therefore overwriting the files that you have saved before which means in the end you will only have one shapefile. But I don't think that was your intention.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I checked files with a print statement, and it does print a list of several csv files I have saved in the folder.

Comment: I am aware of the name overwrite problem. It's something I figured I could tackle next.

Comment: Could you please check the last csv file within the `files` variable. Is it maybe empty?

Comment: It isn't empty! All the files have a few null entries in them, but I wouldn't think that would cause this.

Comment: Then unfortunately I don't know without seeing some example data.

Comment: I've added a little bit to the question if you'd like to mess with it. It's just a sample of it because the files themselves are very long.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the sample file.
The thing is that if you provide a relative filepath like here

```
gdf.to_file('file.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

then the file is saved in your current working directory which is maybe not the one where you want the file to appear and therefore do not search there whether the file exists. If you want to save the shapefile to another working directory then just supply an absolute filepath like in this example:

```
filepath = "C:/users/your/file/path"
gdf.to_file(f"{filepath}/file.shp", driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

This worked for me with your sample data. I could also verify this by loading the file again as a GeoDataFrame like this:

```
gpd_df = gpd.read_file(f"{filepath}/file.shp")
```

Hope that solves it for you as well.

Comment: Thank you intedgar! Unfortunately, this still didn't work for me! After some playing around I think it's an issue with the crs. For some reason the crs from the GeoDataFrame doesn't get attached to the output file. When I run the code, it creates an output file, but when I open it in ArcPro it doesn't contain any points and an "Unknown Coordinate System" error pops up. The weird thing is, the new shapefile does have a correct attribute table! I wonder if it could be a bug with my version of geopandas (0.9.0)?